# Pandas won't rename the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change the name of the columns from "0" to "A" and "1" to "B".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

data = pd.DataFrame()

data = pd.read_csv('rakett.txt', sep="  ", header=None)

data = data.rename(columns={'0': 'newName1', '1': 'newName2'})

print(data)
```

However when i open the dataframe nothing is changed...
[Iamge of dataframe when opened in the variabel explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mewfj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've provided should work for renaming the columns, but it seems there might be an issue with the way the data is loaded from your CSV file. If the column names are not changing as expected, it could be because the column names in the DataFrame are still the default integer-based names.

You can rename the columns after reading the data from the CSV file by specifying the new column names as a list. Here's how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('rakett.txt', sep="  ", header=None)

# Rename the columns
data.columns = ['A', 'B']

print(data)
```

This code reads the data from 'rakett.txt' and then directly assigns the new column names 'A' and 'B' to the DataFrame.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try `{0: 'A', 1: 'B'}` instead of `{'0': 'A', '1': 'B'}`.

Also, you seem to have a separator with more than one character. This might not work when the `pandas.readcsv()` function uses the 'c' engine internally. To change this try adding `engine='python'` like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('rakett.txt', sep="  ", header=None, engine='python')

data = data.rename(columns={0: 'A', 1: 'B'})

print(data)
```

PS: You don't need to initialize the data frame before using `pandas.readcsv()`, this isn't Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your column names are likely not `str` typed; use `int`-typed keys in your `columns` object parameter instead:

```
data.rename(columns={0: 'newName1', 1: 'newName2'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data = data.rename(columns={0: 'newName1', 1: 'newName2'})
```

Answer (score 0):

*1. Import pandas package*
2. Define a dictionary containing ICC rankings*
3. Convert the dictionary into DataFrame*
4. Before renaming the columns*
5. After renaming the columns*

```
import pandas as pd
rankings = {'test': ['India', 'South Africa', 'England',
                            'New Zealand', 'Australia'],
            'odi': ['England', 'India', 'New Zealand',
                            'South Africa', 'Pakistan'],
            't20': ['Pakistan', 'India', 'Australia',
                            'England', 'New Zealand']}
rankings_pd = pd.DataFrame(rankings)
print(rankings_pd)
rankings_pd.rename(columns = {'test':'TEST'}, inplace = True)
print("\nAfter modifying first column:\n", rankings_pd.columns)
```